# Configure celery pidboxes

Tags: python, django, celery, amazon-sqs, kombu

I have configured my project to use a combination of Celery-Kombu0-SQS and Celery pidbox queues get created for each node on which I am running Celery worker. I am trying to suppress/avoid these queues. I went through other blogs and read that this option is disabled by default for SQS but I still see the pidboxes being created.

How can I either suppress the creation or configure the name of the pidbox if it cannot be suppressed?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Or did you figure out how to disable these queues?